# How to convert string to ushort[]

Tags: c#, .net

I have been scouring the web for a solution to the conversion problem I have been facing where I am required to write into the User Memory of a RF Tag. The API accepts an `ushort[]`. I have created an app that accepts ASCII inputs as a test field. For instance, if the user enters `Hurrah`, then I need that to be converted to `ushort[] { 0x4875, 0x7272, 0x6168}` . Here is how far I have gotten with this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AsciiToHexConversionTest()
    {
        IList<ushort> outputList = new List<ushort>();
        var inputStr = "Hurrah";
        IList<char> output = new List<char>();

        char[] values = inputStr.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char letter in values)
        {
            // Get the integral value of the character. 
            var value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);

            // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form. 
            // uncommenting this line results in an error, and I cant figure out how to convert int to hex without it being a string
            //output.Add(string.Format("{0:X}", value));

        }

        // use bitwise or to package two bytes to a ushort value
        for (int i = 0; i < output.ToArray().Length; i++)
        {
            outputList.Add((ushort)((output[i] << 8) | output[i + 1]));
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(outputList, "487572726168");

    }
```

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Convert.ToUInt16(Num); you can use this one where  Num  will be your number which you want to convert in ushort. @purusartha

Comment: @purusartha, what's not working with your approach?

Comment: @DWright, I want to be able to do something like output.Add(string.Format("{0:X}", value)); which stores the hex value as a char.... except the above results in a compile time error

Comment: The char array making up the string is already a 'ushort' array.

Comment: @leppie is right, since the native Char is for UTF-16, it's a two byte wide Char. Ushort is also two bytes wide.  Relevant to this point, Purusartha, your code is packing two character values into each ushort.  Is that a requirement?  Or can you have one character value per ushort?

Comment: @Purusartha, how's it going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I think you are thinking that a number can either be in decimal or binary or hexadecimal, etc. But that's not how it works. Numbers are numeric values that specify magnitude--decimal vs. hexadecimal is just how those values are represented. So the numbers in `listOfUshorts` have a numeric value that can be expressed in either hexadecimal or any other base, such as decimal (the underlying base is actually binary, neither hex or decimal).

I've updated the code below to prove this: I have inserted new `Debug.Asserts` below, where I assert that each item is the expected hexadecimal value.  I also assert their equivalent decimal value, and then I assert that the hexadecimal and decimal values are directly equivalent to each other.

---

**Original**

Seems to me like you basically had it.  However, the only time you need to convert to hex is for human-readable-comparison purposes.  So you don't need two lists (`output` and `outputList`).  Internally you can always deal with the numeric values as they are, without conversion, as long as you always deal with them in the same base (whether decimal or hexadecimal or anything else).

Here's basically the same thing, with a few tweaks. I don't have it as a test fixture, so I don't have `Assert.AreEqual`--I used Debug.Assert instead.  I also put the hex formatting for display/comparison into its own function, since it's only needed for test purposes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ushort[] result = AsciiToHexConversionTest();

            String outputAsHexString = DecodeToHexString(result);

            Debug.Assert(outputAsHexString == "0x4875,0x7272,0x6168");

            Console.WriteLine(outputAsHexString);
            var readKey = Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static ushort[] AsciiToHexConversionTest()
        {
            var inputStr = "Hurrah";

            char[] values = inputStr.ToCharArray();
            List<ushort> listOfUshorts = new List<ushort>();

            ushort mask = (ushort)0x00FF;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 2)
            {
                //This approach assumes stuffing the lower 8 bits of two chars into the upper and lower half of a ushort
                ushort first = values[i];
                ushort second = (ushort)(mask & values[i + 1]); //mask is for safety.  Must ensure that top byte is 0 so that | below goes ok.
                listOfUshorts.Add((ushort)((first << 8) | second));
            }

            //demonstrate hexadecimal values
            Debug.Assert(listOfUshorts[0] == 0x4875);
            Debug.Assert(listOfUshorts[1] == 0x7272);
            Debug.Assert(listOfUshorts[2] == 0x6168);

            //demonstrate decimal values
            Debug.Assert(listOfUshorts[0] == 18549);
            Debug.Assert(listOfUshorts[1] == 29298);
            Debug.Assert(listOfUshorts[2] == 24936);

            //directly demonstrate equality of decimal and hexadecimal representations
            Debug.Assert(0x4875 == 18549);
            Debug.Assert(0x7272 == 29298);
            Debug.Assert(0x6168 == 24936);

            return listOfUshorts.ToArray();
        }

        public static string DecodeToHexString(ushort[] list)
        {
            StringBuilder finalOutput = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                finalOutput.Append(String.Format("0x{0:X},", item));
            }
            finalOutput.Remove(finalOutput.Length - 1, 1); //Remove final comma
            return finalOutput.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, especially for mask... however I need the output to be exactly ushort[] { 0x4875, 0x7272, 0x6148 } . Note that the values have to be in hex..... When I do listOfUInt16s.ToArray(), the values will be in decimal. Is there a way to specify that the value be represented in hex??

Comment: @Purusartha, I've also update to use ushort instead of UInt16, just so it's clear they have the same result.  And I've added a final Debug that shows the result as a comma separated hexadecimal list: `Debug.Assert(finalOutput.ToString() == "0x4875,0x7272,0x6168");`

Comment: You are right the representation does not make a difference. I had to change my algorithm to loop through the ushort[] and write 1 index at a time.... worked perfectly. Thanks for taking the time out to help.

Answer (score 1):

@Purusartha, there is an error in the ushort[] you give, the final hex value should be 0x6168 not 0x6148.  I did it like this:

```
string inputStr = "Hurrah";
char[] values = inputStr.ToCharArray();
ushort[] packed = new ushort[values.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i+=2)
{
    packed[i / 2] = (ushort)(values[i] * 0x100 + values[i + 1]);
}
```